# Как вывести мета-описание по типу страницы

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

В текущем проекте мета-описание выводится через произвольное поле плагина ACF следующим кодом:

```
<?php 
    $meta_desc = get_field('meta-description', get_queried_object_id());

    if(empty($meta_desc)) {
        $meta_desc = '';
    }
?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_desc; ?> "/>
```

Помогите изменить текущий вывод мета-описания таким образом, чтобы для страниц выводить, например, значение поля `page-meta-desc`, а для постов, например, `post-meta-desc`.
Проще говоря, нужно определить тип страницы, и под нужный тип вывести нужное поле как мета-описание.

Comment: Для страниц и постов же вроде используются разные файлы.

Comment: Оба типа страниц используют один файл header.

Comment: get_post_type() - тип страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте is_singular с нужным $post_types: https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_singular

Конкретно ваша задача:

```
<?php 
if (is_singular( 'page' ) ){
    $meta_desc = get_field('page-meta-desc', get_queried_object_id());

    if(empty($meta_desc)) {
        $meta_desc = '';
    }
} else if(is_singular( 'post' ) ){
    $meta_desc = get_field('post-meta-desc', get_queried_object_id());

    if(empty($meta_desc)) {
        $meta_desc = '';
    }
}
?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_desc; ?> "/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть достоточно много ф-ций для проверки типа страницы: `is_single`, `is_singular`, `is_page`, `is_tax`, `is_front_page` и т.д.